# Does the size of a table in terms of storage expands FOUR-TIMES if data type changes from smallint to bigInt?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, types

If I change a column's data type from 'smallint' to 'bigint' for a table having N rows, does this automatically results in physical storage expansion four-times?

Or the implementation makes it dependable on the values stored in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the physical storage for that column has to be increased in size. All of the integer numeric data types are fixed-width columns - the storage for each column, in each row, is of a fixed size. So if you switch from one of those data types to another, the physical storage has to be rearranged.

This is in contrast with, say, the variable-width string data types - `nvarchar(x)` and `varchar(x)` where the amount of storage used varies on each row. Changing these data types by altering their maximum length will not result in any physical storage changes - if `x` is lengthened, it's simply a metadata operation (you're allowed to store longer strings, by definition all existing data is already less than this new maximum) or if `x` is shortened, all rows have to be scanned to confirm that they conform to the new maximum, but if any row is found that doesn't conform, the operation is aborted with an error, rather than performing truncation.

---

So, the size of the *column* changes by a factor of four. The effects on the overall row and table size depend on how many other columns the table contains.